# Getting data from foreign key on view in Laravel 6

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-6

What I am trying to do, is to fetch a row from a table, using a foreign key inside it, that links to another table, and then display a specific column of that row inside a view.

For some context, this is a website about sport events. Inside the view, the user should be able to see the details of the clicked event. Inside those details should be the sport category and the sport. However, I can't find how to do so, in Laravel 6.5.

---

What I have:

**Database tables:**

```
sport_categories (id, name)
sports (id, sport_category_id, name)
events (id, title, sport_category_id, sport_id)
```

**EventsController**

```
public function show(Event $event) 
{
    return view('events.show', ['event' => $event]);
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="event-sport-category">
   <span>Sport Category:</span>
   <span id="show-event-sport-category-label">{{$event->sport_category_id}}</span>
</div>
<div id="event-sport">
   <span>Sport:</span>
   <span id="show-event-sport-label">{{$event->sport_id}}</span>
</div>
```

**SportCategory Model** (empty)

```
class SportCategory extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**Sport Model**

```
class Sport extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Event Model**

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Of course at this point what is returned to the view are just the id columns of the `events` table. How can I return the corresponding `name` of each id?

Answer (score 2):

Acoording to your database setup:

> - sport_categories (id, name)
> - sports (id, sport_category_id, name)
> - events (id, title, sport_category_id, sport_id)

So.. In this response I'm assuming that:

- A `Category` has many `Sport`s
- A `Sport` has many `Event`s

**Notice:** Given the fact that a `Sport` already belongs to a `Category`, you shouldn't need to specify a `category_sport_id` key in the `events` table: the related `sport` row should already have it.

Now, to your question..

> How can I return the corresponding name of each id ?

Defining [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships).

In your `Category.php` model:

```
class SportCategory extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = []; // <---

    // ...

    public function sports() // <---
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sport::class);
    }
}
```

Your `Sport.php` model:

```
class Sport extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = []; // <---

    // ...

    public function events() // <---
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
    }

    public function category() // <---
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SportCategory::class);
    }
}
```

In your `Event.php` model:

```
class Event extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = []; // <---

    // ...

    public function sport() // <---
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sport::class);
    }
}
```

**Notice**: I added a `protected $guarded = [];` in each model, this is tell Laravel to include all the fields when returning it to the view. [Read this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Now that your relationships are been defined, you need to load the relationships before returning the variable to the view. Of course you could load the relationship in the view itself but to optimize your query you [should eager](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) load this objects like so (in this case, lazy eager loading because you are already resolving the object using Model Binding):

```
public function show(Event $event) 
{
    $event->load('sport.category'); // <---

    return view('events.show', ['event' => $event]);
}
```

Now you should have this records in your $event variable: `$event->sport` and the nested `$event->sport->category` so in order to output them in your view just:

```html
<p>  {{ $event->sport->name }} </p>
<!-- ... -->
<p> {{ $event->sport->category->name }} </p>
```

Comment: Okay so I did as you said in the models and the controller, however the view proposes an error. The  ```<p>  {{ $event->sport->name }} </p>``` part works fine, but the ```<p> {{ $event->sport->category->name }} </p>``` part gives an error saying: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object".

Comment: @BillM. check the `category()` relationship on the `Sport` model. It seems that the nested relationship isn't being loaded.

Comment: Alright, I tried removing the 'sport' from $event of the controller, ( ```$event->load('category');``` ) and it returned this error: "Call to undefined relationship [category] on model [App\Event]. ". So I decided to add the ```sportCategory``` function into the Events model ( ```public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SportCategory::class);
    }``` ), which worked for the first view <p> but not the second one again, since it gives the same error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object". If at this point I change the controller event to sport.category, same error.

Comment: @BillM. when you removed the "sport." part of the relatinoship, you are trying to acccess the Category relationship without sports.. which isn't possible given my setup. That's why is important. Related to your second attempt: Yes, you can define the relationship there, but you shouldn't need to do it given the fact that it can be accessed through the Sport model. Maybe is a matter of the keys. I'll update my answer to explicitly mention the primmary/foreign keys.

Comment: Ok, I've added those keys in the `SportCategory` and `Sport` models. Check it out @BillM.

Comment: Uhm, these changes inside the ```Sport``` and ```SportCategory``` models are exactly what I have done in my previous comment... There's no change to the error. The category is still not being loaded for some reason...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205152/discussion-between-kenny-horna-and-bill-m).